# NHibernate second level appfabric cache without regions

Tags: c#, caching, nhibernate, appfabric

On my current project they are using AppFabric cache. But we discovered we are not using it correctly.

If I read the following [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790985%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) correctly. Regions are limited to one cache hosts and named caches span the whole cluster.

We currenlty see the following behavior. NHibernate is creating cache regions even if we specified `CacheType="Named"`. Therefore multiple nodes in our cluster are not used, if we do a restart of the cache cluster.

We would like to only use our named caches without regions.

The config looks like this:

```
<AppFabricProviderSettings CacheType="Named" NamedCacheTypeRegionName="nhibernate" NamedCachesMustExist="false" LockTimeout="30000" LocksRegionName="Locks" />
```

The code to decide what entity gets cached looks something like this:

```
if (condition == true)
{
    mapping.CacheConcurrencyStrategy = "nonstrict-read-write";
    nhConfig.SetCacheConcurrencyStrategy(mapping.EntityName, "nonstrict-read-write", weekCacheName);
}
else if (secondCondition == true)
{
    mapping.CacheConcurrencyStrategy = "nonstrict-read-write";
    nhConfig.SetCacheConcurrencyStrategy(mapping.EntityName, "nonstrict-read-write", dayCacheName);
}
else
{
    mapping.CacheConcurrencyStrategy = "nonstrict-read-write";
    nhConfig.SetCacheConcurrencyStrategy(mapping.EntityName, "nonstrict-read-write", hourCacheName);
}
```

**Can somebody clarify what we are doing wrong and how to only have named caches and not regions?**

I also looked at the code off the [Nhibernate.Caches.AppFabric](https://github.com/SimonTaylor/NHibernate.Caches.AppFabric) and I find it disturbing the keyword region is widely used in the code.

*Our cache works, but sometimes it goes out of memory because all regions are created on the same host*

Comment: I did notice that, I'm trying to [refactor](https://github.com/SathishN/NHibernate.Caches.AppFabric), not to create regions in named cache!